# How to find the radius of convergence of the given series

Tags: real-analysis

For the infinite series $\sum_{ j=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ the Radius of convergence is given by 
$$R=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_n}{a_{ n+1}} \right|.$$ 
My question is, how to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{ j=0}^{\infty}   a_n (1-z) \cdot z^n ?$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Multiply it out, then expand.

Comment: I know. Then I have two series. I don't know how to find the R.O.C. then.

Comment: BTW if $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n/a_{n+1}$ exists then it is the radius of convergence. In general, use the Hadamard Radius Formula,

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{ j=0}^{\infty} a_n (1-z) \cdot z^n=(1-z)\sum_{ j=0}^{\infty} a_n \cdot z^n$$

The $(1-z)$ does not affect convergence.